# os.listdir() not showing contents of directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```py
files = [f for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd() + "\\folder") if os.path.isfile(f)]
for file in files:
    print("hello")
```

I am running this from the directory which contains a folder called "folder". This folder has 4 files in it. This should print "hello" four times in my head - but it doesn't.

What have I misunderstood?

PS Do I need to use `os.getcwd()` here? I figure it would be cleaner to just use a relative path, but that also doesn't work.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest breaking this down into smaller parts and inspecting them so you can ask a narrower question. Look at what `os.listdir()` returns, *before* the `isfile()` filtering. Look at what your `files` list contains. Generally: Figure out exactly what's going wrong *before* you ask your question, so you can focus your question only on that specific issue, and remove everything that isn't essential to the problem itself.

Comment: As Charles says, you can quite easily debug this yourself, we can't easily debug it without your file system

Comment: consider using `os.path.join`

Comment: Seconding what @Charles said, also check that you're in the right place by checking what `os.getcwd()` returns.

Comment: *nod*. Most of us won't be able to run your code just because it uses backslashes, and those don't work outside Windows.-

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `os.path.isfile(f)` you're asking if `f` is a file *inside your current directory*, not inside `folder`. Replace your code with:

```
[f for f in os.listdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "folder")) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join("folder", f))]
```

I've also taken the liberty of using `os.path.join` to avoid direct concatenation of file and folder names as strings, since slashes can be a bit iffy.

And for the record, no you don't need to use `os.getcwd()` here (but I left it there anyways).